# Need Debian driver for DWA-130 rev F1

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

Can't get my wireless adapter working.  It's D-Link DWA 130 rev F1.  There's a good deal of discussion about this in the Ubuntu world, but it doesn't seem to work on Debian.  The chip-set appears to be completely different from the previous rev (E1).  The net seems to think that the appropriate driver is rtl8192cu.  I have tried several different times, but no luck so far.  I am running Debian Jessie.

Here's one approach: following advice [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2272602) I looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471208/realtek-wireless-adapter-issues-rtl8192ce-and-rtl8192cu) and followed the recipe given in the first answer . . . making some substitutions.  (Linux-generic-headers doesn't exist for Debian, for example.) But, it didn't work.

My current theory is that the kernel goes by the device's USB identity to decide which module to load for it.  Checking the table of known identities vs the *lsusb* listing, I see that mine (2001:3C25) isn't listed.  Therefore, I guess that the module must be changed to include that, which means recompiling the module from source.

If that can be done, I'd appreciate someone who would walk me through it. If not, what *should* I do?

(Of course, like a good FOSS-citizen, I will send a note to amend the list, but I won't feel confident that I can until I can get the bleedin' thing to work.)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Marco, I have expanded the original post with some specifics of one thing I tried.  (There is also another, which didn't work.) Hope this gives you enough to chew on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian should not be any different than any other distro, other than kernel version.

As always, device drivers depend on the kernel.

The correct driver for the `DWA130F1` with a `USB ID of 2001:3c25` is `rt2800usb`. A patch adding this device to the USB tables of that driver was submitted to the kernel as commit ea345c145ff23197eab34d0c4d0c8a93d7bea8c6 by Scott Branden  on Mar 16, 2015. It is a part of kernel 4.1-rcX and has been added to most of the stable kernels. None of the stable kernels have yet been released, but this change will be in the next release.

To add this driver on a temporary basis, do the following as root:

```
modprobe rt2800usb

echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

Unfortunately, those steps will be needed after every reboot.